# Post processing on UNION result cypher query neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have written below query using lucene indexing . I know UNION doesn't have  pagination support in neo4j . I want to post process the 
final result of this query to paginate the result .

```
START user=node:peopleSearch('username:abhay*') RETURN user , user.createdDate as time UNION START rel= Relationship:peopleSearch('skillName:Java23') RETURN StartNode(rel) as user , StartNode(rel).createdDate as time
```

I have followed this [link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725) . But it giving me error on UNION RESULT .

I need to post process the union final result to paginate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced github issue is not yet resolved, so post processing of `UNION` is not yet possible.

As a workaround in the meantime you can split up your query into two queries. The first one combines the index lookups and returns node ids:

```
START user=node:peopleSearch('username:abhay*') RETURN id(user) as id     
UNION 
START rel= Relationship:peopleSearch('skillName:Java23') RETURN id(StartNode(rel)) as id
```

On client side, collect the returned IDs into an array and submit the second query using a cypher parameter:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE ID(n) IN {myIdArray}
WITH n
// placeholder for rest of this query
```

where the parameter value of `myIdArray` is the returned IDs from step1.

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448935/order-by-the-result-of-union-of-subqueries) a few weeks ago, and it turns out Cypher currently does not support [post-UNION processing](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725).

This means that you should filter both inputs of the union using the same condition.

Alternatively (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41449711/3580502)), if you can use APOC, you can post-process the results of a query:

```
CALL apoc.cypher.run("... UNION ...", NULL) YIELD n, r, x
WHERE ...
RETURN n, r, x;
```

Update: this is now possible in Neo4j 4.0 using the [`CALL {subquery}` construct](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/call-subquery/).