# ORDER BY the result of UNION of subqueries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to compute the [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-union) of multiple subqueries and sort the result using [ORDER BY](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-order).

So I'd like to run this query (written in pseudo-Cypher):

```
(RETURN 2 AS x
UNION
RETURN 1 AS x)
ORDER BY x
```

And get the following result:

```
╒═══╕
│x  │
╞═══╡
│1  │
├───┤
│2  │
└───┘
```

Is there a way to do this? As `ORDER BY` is always tied to a single [`WITH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-with)/[`RETURN`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-return) clause, I do not think this is possible, nor can I think of a good workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Cypher language does not yet support [Post-Union processing](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725).

However, as a workaround, you should be able to use the APOC procedure [apoc.cypher.run](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_cypher_execution_2) to perform the UNION operation in a "subroutine", and then perform the post-UNION processing in the main Cypher query. For example:

```
CALL apoc.cypher.run("RETURN 2 AS x UNION RETURN 1 AS x", NULL) YIELD value
RETURN value.x AS x
ORDER BY x;
```

**Update:** this is now possible in Neo4j 4.0+ using the [`CALL {subquery}` construct](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/call-subquery/):

```
CALL {
  RETURN 2 AS x
  UNION ALL
  RETURN 1 AS x"
}
RETURN x
ORDER BY x;
```

Comment: Thanks for referring the related issue and also providing a workaround.

Comment: Such a useful answer to a very common use case. Thanks for sharing this one.

Comment: Updated the answer with the new `CALL` clause.