# Cypher/Neo4j - Adding a constrain after union clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to do a query builder and I need to include a constrain to the outcome resulting from a union clause. I want this output of the union clause to be filtered from a list of nodes that i do not want at the end of it.

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(x) 
WHERE ( 'filter1' IN r.property or  'filter2' IN r.property ) 
RETURN n,r,x 
UNION 
MATCH (n)-[r]->(x) 
WHERE ( 'foo2' IN n.property OR 'foo2' IN x.property 
RETURN n,r,x
```

As an example I would need to include a final filter to this query that avoids all nodes that are called 'whatever'.

How to do that? simply with a where clause at the end of the clause would work?

Comment: The query should give the same result than this example"
MATCH (n)-[r]->(x) where ( 'filter1' IN r.property or  'filter2' IN r.property ) WHERE N.ID NOT EQUALS 'EXAMPLE' OR X.ID NOT EQUALS 'EXAMPLE' RETURN n,r,x 
UNION 
MATCH (n)-[r]->(x) where ( 'foo2' IN n.property OR 'foo2' IN x.property) WHERE N.ID NOT EQUALS 'EXAMPLE' OR X.ID NOT EQUALS 'EXAMPLE RETURN n,r,x
"

Comment: Please edit this comment to the question. Note the query is not syntactically correct, there is an apostrophe missing after `'EXAMPLE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448935/order-by-the-result-of-union-of-subqueries) a few weeks ago, and it turns out Cypher currently does not support [post-UNION processing](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725).

This means that you should filter both inputs of the union using the same condition.

Alternatively (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41449711/3580502)), if you can use APOC, you can post-process the results of a query:

```
CALL apoc.cypher.run("... UNION ...", NULL) YIELD n, r, x
WHERE ...
RETURN n, r, x;
```

**Update:** this is now possible in Neo4j 4.0 using the [`CALL {subquery}` construct](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/call-subquery/).

Comment: Gabor, the answer given to the question you referenced has a solution by using APOC procedures. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks - well, technically it can, but I don't think repeating the same condition twice is such a bad thing. For [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448935/order-by-the-result-of-union-of-subqueries), the trick was the ordering which cannot be achieved so easily. But I'll update the answer with this.

Comment: Thanks. I finally ended up adding the same condition to each of the inputs of the union and works but I cant use APOC since I do the query using py2neo. MATCH (n)-[r]->(x) where ( 'condition1' IN r.property ) AND (r.property2= 'condition2') AND NOT (n.id = 'COMMON_CONSTRAIN' OR x.id = 'COMMON_CONSTRAIN')) RETURN n as object_node,r as relationship,x as predicate UNION MATCH (n)-[r]->(x) where ('EXPAND_NODE' = n.id OR 'EXPAND_NODE' = x.BEL ) AND NOT (n.id = 'COMMON_CONSTRAIN' OR x.id = 'COMMON_CONSTRAIN')) RETURN n as object_node,r as relationship,x as predicate

Comment: "The query binds aims to bind one query and the neighbor nodes of a node in the graph deleting from the resulting query a list of nodes by id"