# neo4j javascript API: SORT and COLLECT a UNIONS MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have to run a query based on union of queries, and I have to apply COLLECT and SORT of the results 
(I am on neo4j 3.5)

So my starting pseudo-code is the following:

```
var session = driver.session();
  return session
.run("QUERY_1 return value as COL1, value2 as COL2 UNION QUERY_2 return value as COL1, value2 as COL",{paramslit}) 
.then(result => {
      session.close();
      return result.records.map(record => { return new RESULT(...)}
});
    })
    .catch(error => {
      session.close();
      throw error;
    });
```

My problem is that I need to get the result of col2 as a set, so I need to apply collect to it in the cypher query; but the collect should be applied after the union because both QUERY_1 and QUERY_2 can return values for a given col1

QUERY_1 and QUERY_2 are already pretty complicated and I don't think there is a way to get the output of those queries with a single query without UNION

For cypher only code I know that there is the **apoc.cypher.run**
but I have not been able to make it work as expected within the **session.run** code

Comment: What do you want to sort? Also, you say you want to return COL2 as a "set"; do you mean a list with distinct elements? In addition, do you want to aggregate COL1 as well, or do you want to get the set of COL2 values for each distinct COL1 value, or do you want something else?

Comment: If this was a single RETURN query without UNIONS , I would do WITH COL1, COL2  ORDER BY COL1 RETURN COL1, COLLECT(COL2) as SET_OF_COL2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In neo4j 4.0, a new [subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#query-call-subquery) feature was added to Cypher, and it supports [post-UNION processing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#subquery-post-union).

You can use that feature to do what you want. Here is the new Cypher pseudo-code:

```
CALL {
  QUERY_1 return value as COL1, value2 as COL2
  UNION
  QUERY_2 return value as COL1, value2 as COL2
}
RETURN COL1, COLLECT(COL2) as SET_OF_COL2
```

Comment: Hi cybersam. Was aware of that and was hoping to find ajouter way to do it in version 3.5.  I gave UP and migrated to 4?0

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41449711/974731).